# SetTimeout how to do it?

Tags: javascript

I want to make this code run after 20 seconds with setTimeout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   soundcloud.addEventListener('onPlayerReady', function(player, data) {
     player.api_play();
   });
</script>
```

The code works correctly alone but I don't know how to delay it. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {

   soundcloud.addEventListener('onPlayerReady', function(player, data) {
     player.api_play();
   });

}, 20000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will delay the execution of player.api_play() **after** the `onPlayerReady` event is fired. The code by @alex will the delay registering of the handler for the `onPlayerReady` event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   soundcloud.addEventListener('onPlayerReady', function(player, data) {
     setTimeout(function(player) {
         player.api_play();
     }, 2000);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: This is probably what the OP wants, I don't think they asked specifically what they wanted. Also, according to [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) *Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer.* Is there any reason to do it here, i.e. won't the inner function have access to its parent `player` (or has Friday ruined my brain)?

Comment: +1 for doing most probably what the OP wants, and glad my brain is still OK :)